# Password token on registration email

Tags: 7

Okay I managed to create a password token to be used on email registration message with a custom module. Works fine.

However, using this on commerce checkout ([Commerce Checkout Login](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_login)) where users are allowed for inline registration does not seem to work.

Aren't they the same event and the same form? Why would this custom module not work on registration form other than the one located in /user/register?

```
function my_module_token_info() {
    $info['tokens']['user']['password'] = array(
    'name' => t('Password'),
    'description' => t('The password by the user'),
    );
return $info;
}
/**
* Implements hook_tokens().
* */
function my_module_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
    $replacements = array();
    $url_options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
    if (isset($options['language'])) {
        $url_options['language'] = $options['language'];
    }
    if ($type == 'user' && !empty($data['user'])) {
        $account = $data['user'];
        foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
            switch ($name) {
                case 'password':
                    $replacements[$original] = $account->password;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $replacements;
}
```